# Rearrange/sort list by largest, smallest, second largest, second smallest etc

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

Given an array of integers, how can I sort them by : largest-smallest-2nd largest - 2nd smallest?

I'm trying to :
- Duplicate and sort an array in order ascending and descending
- Create the sorted array by picking the head of each arrays describes as above

I am not familiar with Haskell programming but here's what I've done

```
sort :: [Int] -> [Int]
sort [] = []
sort (x:xs) = sort smaller ++ [x] ++ sort larger
  where
    smaller = filter (<= x) xs
    larger = filter (> x) xs

wave :: [Int] -> [Int]
wave [] = []
wave [x] = [x]
wave (x:xs) = if length (x:xs)>1 
    then :
        ascending = sort (x:xs)
        descending = reverse (ascending)
        iterator = length(x:xs)
        if iterator > 0 && (length(ascending)==0 || length(descending)==0)
            then do wave(x:xs) = head(descending) + head(ascending)
                tail(descending)
                tail(ascending)
```

Thanks by advance for your help

Comment: `then :` is bad syntax. `:` does not belong there. If you have several definitions you can put them into one `let`, as `let { a = ... ; b = ... ; c = ... } in ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`braid` function intercalates two list elem by elem. We next apply `braid` to the list ordered in ascending and descending. Finally, since we end up with the orginal list duplicated, we take just the length of the original list.

```
braid :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]    
braid []     as     = as
braid ds     []     = ds
braid (d:ds) (a:as) = d:a:braid ds as

wave :: [Int] -> [Int]
wave xs = take (length xs) braided 
  where asc  = sort xs
        desc = reverse asc
        braided = braid desc asc
```

### Benchmark Edit:

despite of the fact that I think my implementation is easier to understand for haskell beginers, I got to say that after having benckmarked my solution against ƛƛƛ's solution, mine is ~ 4 to 7 times slower than his/her.

For One hundred thousand length list:

- mine: 211 ms
- ƛƛƛ's: 53 ms

For One million length list:

- mine: 3.8 sec
- ƛƛƛ's: 547 ms

### Edit Two: Don't use `reverse`

Replacing `desc = reverse asc` by `desc = sortOn Down xs` produces same speed program as ƛƛƛ's applicative solution and willness comprehension list implementation.

Comment: try `take (length xs) (braid (reverse $ sort xs) (sort xs))`. I wonder if it could be faster. (still it will be slower than the other one of course, as that one directly produces the reversed list).

Comment: the problem is actually `reverse $ sort xs`, replacing it by `sortOn Down` produces same speed code than other solutions. I didn't expect reverse to be such slow

Comment: @ƛƛƛ criterion library

Answer (score 4):

`frontEndSort` consumes a list `xs`, it sorts its elements in descending order. Next, pair each element in `xs` with element from the same list but in ascending order. Convert each pair to a list then flatten the whole list. Finally, we take as many elements as in `xs`.

```
frontEndSort :: [Int] -> [Int] 
frontEndSort xs = take (length xs) $ do
    (x, y) <- zip <$> sortBy (comparing Down) <*> sort $ xs
    [x, y]
```

Comment: nice solution. 4 times faster than the one I proposed. Only one suggest `sortBy (comparing Down)` can bu substitute by `sortOn Down`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use the zipping:

```
import Data.Ord

frontEndSort :: [Int] -> [Int] 
frontEndSort xs =
    zipWith (flip const) xs
       ( concat . getZipList . traverse ZipList
                $ [sortBy (comparing Down) xs, sort xs] )
```

Here `traverse ZipList :: [[b]] -> ZipList [b]` so it already produces the pairs as lists, not tuples.